# Grab the SelectedIndex for a row a button was clicked in

Tags: c#, webforms

I have two buttons inside a GridView that is inside an UpdatePanel.

For both of these buttons I need to grab the rowId/selectedIndex for the row the button was clicked in.  I also need to do something extra depending on which buttons was clicked.  One will redirect (edit) the other (request letter) will update a sql database.  Both of those functions requires the selectedIndex of the row.

The buttons are the last two buttons.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" EnableModelValidation="True" 
            DataKeyNames="id" Width="100%" 
            AllowSorting="True" CssClass="Grid" GridLines="None" 
            onrowcreated="SubpoenaGrid_RowCreated" ID="SubpoenaGrid" 
            onrowdatabound="SubpoenaGrid_RowDataBound" 
            <!--onselectedindexchanged="SubpoenaGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" -->
            onrowcommand="SubpoenaGrid_RowCommand">

            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="HiddenColumn" 
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="HiddenColumn">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HiddenColumn"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="HiddenColumn"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" 
                    SortExpression="type" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="status" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dateRequested" HeaderText="Request Date" 
                    SortExpression="dateRequested" DataFormatString="{0:d}" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="locName" HeaderText="Recipient" 
                    SortExpression="locName" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Debtor" 
                    SortExpression="name" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="edit" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="requestLet" HeaderText="Request Letter?" Text="Request Letter" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert last two columns (Bound Fields) to template fields, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="edit" Text="Edit" OnCommand="OnGridViewItemCommand" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request Letter?">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="requestLet" Text="Request Letter" OnCommand="OnGridViewItemCommand" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then in `code-behind` implement `OnGridViewItemCommand` method like this:

```
protected void OnGridViewItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    int dataItemIndex = row.DataItemIndex; //index of selected item in underlying datasource
    int itemIndex = row.RowIndex; // index of selected item in Rows collection

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "edit":
            //edit action code
            break;

        case "requestLet":
            //request Letter action code
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: I found a different but similar solution than this, but I like this one better than the one I found.  Thank you.